# How to load images from URL in JavaFx if recieving HTTP Error 403

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I was trying to help someone out with what I thought was a duplicate and a simple question, but it turned out to be slightly more complicated and I couldn't give a definite answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250901/javafx-add-an-image-to-the-gridpane?noredirect=1#comment73636418_43250901) is the original question.

I tried the code with different images on sites using the https protocol and none worked. I then took some images and added them to sites that use http protocol and they worked.

So, the questions is how do you load an image in a ImageView if the site hosting the image is using https protocol?

Comment: I don't think it's an https issue.  When I download https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/250163910454280192/296377451599364107/Untitled.png using a java.net.URLConnection, I get an HTTP 403 Forbidden response.  Setting a `User-Agent` header in the HTTP request solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I just research HTTP ERROR 403.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not an https issue.  It seems cdn.discordapp.com requires a `User-Agent` header in the HTTP request.  Furthermore, the site appears to only accept certain formats for User-Agent.  It turns out the User-Agent supplied by [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is accepted:

```
Image createImage(String url)
throws IOException {
    URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)");

    try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream()) {
        return new Image(stream);
    }
}
```

Without a User-Agent header in the request, the site gives an HTTP 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: About to have a meeting. I am going to test it when I get back to my desk.\